# Show error message if user leaves datagridview cell blank

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, validating

I'm trying to validate a users data in a datagridview. Right now I have a column that needs to show an error message if left blank by the user. I've figured out how to show an error message if the datagridview cell is expecting a number but the user types a string. So how can I change this code to show an error message if the user leaves a datagridview cell blank.

```
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then 'checking numeric value for column 1 only
       Dim value As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
       For Each c As Char In value
           If Not Char.IsDigit(c) Then
               MessageBox.Show("Please Enter numeric Value")
               DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = String.Empty
               Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is the possibility that the cell is Nothing, do not try to apply the ToString(), instead assign the Value property and then test against Nothing and then using the [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) operator against an empty string

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then 'checking numeric value for column 1 only
   Dim cellData = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
   if cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then
       MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Value")
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Dim value = cellData.ToString()
   For Each c As Char In value
      ......
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to implement this I get "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."

Comment: Added a check for DBNull (data coming from a database where you get DBNull.Value instead of Nothing). Requires the Imports of Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace